# Change both http and https port on caddy

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I'm having trouble setting a custom http and https port on caddy in my Caddyfile and could not find an answer using google and stackoverflow

I can set a custom http port like this :

```
http://example.com:2015
```

but I can't set a custom https port

```
http://example.com:2015
https://example.com:2016
```

as caddy only reads the first line as valid.

Starting the file with `https://example.com:2016` will try to bind http to port 80 which is already taken

I simply want to bind http to port 2015 and https to port 2016

Here is my current Caddyfile:

```
http://example.com:2015
https://example.com:2016
gzip
log access.log
basicauth / username password
filemanager / /path {
    database dbname.db
    no_auth
}
```

thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using multiple hosts

```
http://example.com:2015 {
tls off
gzip
log access.log
basicauth / username password
 filemanager / /path {
 database dbname.db
 no_auth
 }
}

https://example.com:2016 {
tls self_signed
gzip
log access.log
basicauth / username password
 filemanager / /path {
 database dbname.db
 no_auth
 }
}
```

If you wish for Caddys Automagic HTTPS you will need to use 443 but if you want to supply your own cert or self_sign (or us DNS challenge) then you should be ok.

Also well worth checking out https://caddy.community/

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed